# Comparing a char of text to a single char using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison

I am having problems comparing a string of text to a single letter and count how many letters are in the string. I only need to compare the single letter to its matching case, such as the letter "z" matches "z", but "z" does not match "Z". Here is what I got so far:

```
/**********************************************************************
* compares the letter to each letter in the string of text and counts the
* number of the matching letters
***********************************************************************/
int countLetters(char letter, char * text)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (char * p = text; *p; p++)
    {  
       if (letter == *p)
       {
          count++;
       }
    }

    return count;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Prompts the user for a line of input, calls countLetters(), and displays
* the number of letters.
***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
    char letter;
    char text;
    int count = 0;
    char * pText;

    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> letter;
    cout << "Enter text: ";
    cin.ignore(2);
    cin >> text;

    pText = &text;

    count = countLetters(letter, pText);
    cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is how it looks when I run the code:

```
Enter a letter: z
Enter text: There are no Z's here
Number of 'z's: 1
```

This is what I expect to happen when I run the code:

```
Enter a letter: z
Enter text: There are no Z's here
Number of 'z's: 0
```

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not allocated space for storing the string in `text`. Therefore, you program invokes undefined behavior and you are getting unexpected result.
Either declare `text` as an array or allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: To declare 'text' as array would I code: "char text[256]" ? By making this change I am getting an error from the compiler saying that "'char (*)[256]' cannot be converted to 'char*'" in assignment. How do I correctly declare 'text' as an array in this instance?

Comment: @starkiller I suggest using `std::string` or at the very least `std::vector`.

Comment: @starkiller; After allocating space for array change `pText = &text;` to `pText = text;`.